# Disable IK effect for a model's certain animations (and keep for the rest)

Tags: animation, bones, inverse-kinematics

I have a question set in the title - I have a model where I use an IK structure to affect maniopulation with 2 handed weapon, it works the way to match the top hand of an imitated weapon in the secondary hand, I like the results but the thing is I export-read(fbx) the model at c++ code for further development and I found out IK effect applies to all the animations created for the model, where I absolutely dont need it. Is there way in Blender to isolate IK effect only for requested animations? I played a bit with channel settings for the bone affected by IK but it did nothing :( Thank you :)

Comment: will it help if you give it an IK FK switch the good old way?

Comment: do you mean removing level of influence at the IK menu? if you do, it doesnt help - for some reason the exported model keeps the current state of this influence , means I have IK on all of animations or I dont do any :)

Comment: No. IK/FK rig is more than that. In blender it requires functioning bone constraints in order to work. Seeing that you need to export the rig with fbx then I'm afraid it won't work and there's currently no way to export blender's constraint functionality in fbx. I could be wrong but tis what I've always remembered.

Comment: All right, thank you, mate, seems then I have to rebuild these animations with manual positionning of the supporting palm, lets hope it doenst enrage me :)